# How to pass result for CURL request from another domain

Tags: php, curl

I have a function that will give some results.

Suppose anyone connecting to my `url` with `CURL` and trying to get result, how should I return result for the `CURL`.

I need to pass `JSON` in return of that `CURL`

Is that I need to echo the result or return?

I tested with,

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $myURL); // here passed my url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

In the url I am doing this,

```
$model = new Application_Model_Listings();
$result['communtityDetails'] = $model->getCommunityWidgetDetails();
$result = json_encode($result['communtityDetails']);
// return $result; or echo $result ??
```

`CURL` connection is happening, but result is not getting.

How should I pass this result??

Comment: just `echo $result` so anyone who is connecting to your page will get the JSON string, you may also add the `header( 'Content-Type: text/json' )` before the echo

Comment: I tried but nothing is returning, is that because of echoing `json_encode()`

Comment: check what $result is contails if its JSON then no need to do json_encode again just echo the $result.

Comment: The result I am getting is an array and then doing `json_encode`

Comment: Got it, but it is returning some other details as well, how to avoid it and return only json